# Sticky element on bottom of element using top?

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

I have two (variable height) stacked elements in a scrolling container.

When the bottom one is below the bottom of the container, I want to show part of it stuck to the bottom.

So I have the element `position: sticky` and positioned it to be `calc(100%-2em)` from the top, which should put it 2em above the bottom of the element.

If the position is `absolute`, it's positioned as expected. But with `position: sticky` it's doing the opposite of what I want, it's stickied only when scrolled to where it should be.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px; height: 100px; background: black; margin: 2em auto; color: white; overflow-y: scroll;
}

#bottom {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(100% - 2em);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin justo sem, egestas eget massa sit amet, volutpat facilisis orci. Aenean tristique pulvinar viverra. Integer dui nunc, sodales id mi vitae, dignissim volutpat nisl. Sed ac tristique ipsum. Nulla quis metus id massa sagittis interdum. Maecenas egestas imperdiet maximus. Etiam vehicula metus sit amet tellus posuere feugiat. Mauris non nisl felis. Suspendisse eu elementum justo. Nulla a semper nisi. Aliquam posuere pulvinar bibendum. Cras eget sem eget nunc rhoncus maximus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    <p>Ut suscipit, augue sed eleifend cursus, quam urna tempus turpis, et consequat neque nisl vel magna. Morbi et fringilla est, eget efficitur nulla. Cras nec finibus sapien. Aenean vitae mauris auctor, ornare sapien et, consectetur eros. Nullam maximus eu augue sed blandit. Aliquam ligula sem, pellentesque quis eleifend id, venenatis sit amet nibh. Curabitur aliquam dolor lacus, non sollicitudin nulla gravida nec. Sed diam odio, sodales sed pretium lobortis, accumsan et nulla. Proin nec posuere nibh. Sed ullamcorper neque eu eros sodales tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris et purus purus. Duis in pulvinar tortor. Morbi fringilla elit eget augue aliquet vulputate vel ut felis. Morbi in est suscipit ex consequat lobortis dapibus id augue. Nulla sagittis, erat vitae tincidunt faucibus, nulla nulla fermentum elit, vitae viverra mi augue sit amet tellus. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"><h3>bottom</h3>
  <p>Phasellus malesuada, ipsum vel ullamcorper elementum, eros leo eleifend nisi, at scelerisque erat lorem id lorem. Mauris vestibulum massa ac bibendum pretium. Cras non tempus nibh, vel finibus tortor. Nulla posuere justo erat, id elementum lectus porttitor in. Nullam leo nibh, dictum ut mauris eget, tristique malesuada nunc. Phasellus vestibulum elit nec ex mollis, sed ultricies est sagittis. Nullam faucibus urna non tortor efficitur, at aliquet sapien dapibus. Aliquam condimentum dapibus neque, imperdiet egestas massa convallis tincidunt. Nam ultrices urna in sem posuere placerat. Praesent sem erat, dignissim et magna sed, luctus cursus lacus. Mauris sed nisi sed est facilisis euismod a quis mauris. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"But with position: sticky it's doing the opposite of what I want"_ - that's because sticky _is_ the opposite of what you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position: _"A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed until it reaches the boundary of its parent."_ - you want it to be the other way around, fixed _before_ it reaches said threshold.

Comment: Or to put it in simpler terms, you could say sticky is to keep an element in view that would otherwise have disappeared because of the position you scrolled the container element to - not vice versa. What you want, is currently not possible using CSS alone, I think - you will have to involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery may be your solution. Have a look at the example below, it will show the `#bottom` div if the user scrolled over the `#top` div.

Here are the changes:

1. Added a div, `#placeholder` of the height same as the `#bottom` div when hidden, which is used to detect the position that the `#bottom` div should show
2. Added the jQuery function

Explaining the jQuery code:

- `jQuery(window).scroll` makes the code run whenever the user scrolls.
- `$(window).scrollTop()` gets the current scroll position, the `$( window ).height()` part makes the 'detector line' at the bottom of the window. `-32` is because the height of `#bottom` div is 2em, which equals to 32px.
- `x` is the variable that stores when should the `#bottom` div show up (the scroll position)

```js
x = $("#placeholder").offset().top
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $( window ).height() - 32 > x) {
  x = $("#bottom").offset().top
  $("#bottom").css({"position": "initial"});
  $("#placeholder").css({"display":"none"});
} else {
  $("#bottom").css({"position": "fixed"});
  $("#placeholder").css({"display":"block"});
}
});
```

```css
#bottom {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100% - 2em);
}

#placeholder {
  height: calc(2em);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data" style="position: fixed; top: 0;"></div>
<div id="hide">123</div>
 <div id="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin justo sem, egestas eget massa sit amet, volutpat facilisis orci. Aenean tristique pulvinar viverra. Integer dui nunc, sodales id mi vitae, dignissim volutpat nisl. Sed ac tristique ipsum. Nulla quis metus id massa sagittis interdum. Maecenas egestas imperdiet maximus. Etiam vehicula metus sit amet tellus posuere feugiat. Mauris non nisl felis. Suspendisse eu elementum justo. Nulla a semper nisi. Aliquam posuere pulvinar bibendum. Cras eget sem eget nunc rhoncus maximus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin justo sem, egestas eget massa sit amet, volutpat facilisis orci. Aenean tristique pulvinar viverra. Integer dui nunc, sodales id mi vitae, dignissim volutpat nisl. Sed ac tristique ipsum. Nulla quis metus id massa sagittis interdum. Maecenas egestas imperdiet maximus. Etiam vehicula metus sit amet tellus posuere feugiat. Mauris non nisl felis. Suspendisse eu elementum justo. Nulla a semper nisi. Aliquam posuere pulvinar bibendum. Cras eget sem eget nunc rhoncus maximus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin justo sem, egestas eget massa sit amet, volutpat facilisis orci. Aenean tristique pulvinar viverra. Integer dui nunc, sodales id mi vitae, dignissim volutpat nisl. Sed ac tristique ipsum. Nulla quis metus id massa sagittis interdum. Maecenas egestas imperdiet maximus. Etiam vehicula metus sit amet tellus posuere feugiat. Mauris non nisl felis. Suspendisse eu elementum justo. Nulla a semper nisi. Aliquam posuere pulvinar bibendum. Cras eget sem eget nunc rhoncus maximus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
    <p>Ut suscipit, augue sed eleifend cursus, quam urna tempus turpis, et consequat neque nisl vel magna. Morbi et fringilla est, eget efficitur nulla. Cras nec finibus sapien. Aenean vitae mauris auctor, ornare sapien et, consectetur eros. Nullam maximus eu augue sed blandit. Aliquam ligula sem, pellentesque quis eleifend id, venenatis sit amet nibh. Curabitur aliquam dolor lacus, non sollicitudin nulla gravida nec. Sed diam odio, sodales sed pretium lobortis, accumsan et nulla. Proin nec posuere nibh. Sed ullamcorper neque eu eros sodales tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris et purus purus. Duis in pulvinar tortor. Morbi fringilla elit eget augue aliquet vulputate vel ut felis. Morbi in est suscipit ex consequat lobortis dapibus id augue. Nulla sagittis, erat vitae tincidunt faucibus, nulla nulla fermentum elit, vitae viverra mi augue sit amet tellus. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
  <div id="bottom"><h3>bottom</h3>
  <p>Phasellus malesuada, ipsum vel ullamcorper elementum, eros leo eleifend nisi, at scelerisque erat lorem id lorem. Mauris vestibulum massa ac bibendum pretium. Cras non tempus nibh, vel finibus tortor. Nulla posuere justo erat, id elementum lectus porttitor in. Nullam leo nibh, dictum ut mauris eget, tristique malesuada nunc. Phasellus vestibulum elit nec ex mollis, sed ultricies est sagittis. Nullam faucibus urna non tortor efficitur, at aliquet sapien dapibus. Aliquam condimentum dapibus neque, imperdiet egestas massa convallis tincidunt. Nam ultrices urna in sem posuere placerat. Praesent sem erat, dignissim et magna sed, luctus cursus lacus. Mauris sed nisi sed est facilisis euismod a quis mauris. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
```